# How does google Big Query handle table updates with missing fields?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm interested in using a streaming pipeline from google pub/sub to big query, I wanted to know how it would handle a case where an updated json object is sent with missing fields/branches that are presently already in a big query table / schema. For example will it set the value in the table to empty/null, retain what's in the table and update fields/branches that are present, or simply fail because the sent object does not match the schema one to one.

Comment: Could you clarify how you plan to configure the pipeline? Do you mean to use one of the Google-provided Cloud Dataflow templates - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still investigating the feasibility, but I may either use a client library (java) to build a custom pipeline or use one of the Dataflow templates you linked.